# Barra de progreso en Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Necesito crear una barra de progreso, debido a que tengo una pequeña ventana en TKinter donde cargo un archivo excel en un dataframe de pandas contiene cerca de 350,000 registros y tarda bastante en cargalo, entonces quiero introducir una barra de progreso en ese lapso, pero no se como capturar el tiempo que tardar en cargar o el tamaño del archivo para que cargue la barra.

```
#Librerias
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

#Funciones
ruta = ''
def abrir():
    '''
    Regresa la ruta absoluta del archivo
    '''
    global ruta
    ruta = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Abrir",filetypes = (("Fichero Excel 97-2003","*.xls"),("Fichero Excel","*.xlsx")))


#Ventana principal
root = Tk()

#Propiedades Ventanas
root.title('Report')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.geometry('200x200')

#Botones
    #Abrir archivo
l1 = Label(root, text="Agrega el archivo")
l1.pack()
b1 = Button(root,text="Abrir", command=abrir, width='10')
b1.pack()
    #Barra de progreso
pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode='indeterminate')
pb.pack()


#Loop Principal
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Javier no es tan simple como parece. Primero de todo, para conseguir  una medida real del progreso hay que leer el archivo en fragmentos (otra cosa es una barra indeterminada), este proceso en si mismo crea una sobrecarga que no se si realmente merece la pena sola para mostrar una barra de progreso. Por otro lado, al ser un procedimiento síncrono va a bloquear la GUI, con o  sin barra necesitas usar un hilo o proceso distinto para evitar que Tkinter se congele mientras se carga el DF. ¿La GUI solo sirve para que el usuario cargue el DF o después será usada para trabajar con los datos?

Comment: En el caso de querer usar una barra de progreso indeterminada entonces no necesitamos saber el estado del proceso, lo único que hay que resolver es evitar el bloqueo de la GUI mientras Pandas lee el fichero y crea el DF en memoria.

Comment: Es para que carguen el archivo y después de cargar el archivo seleccionen un identificador y eso sería todo el programa realizara una exploración de datos y generara unas tablas en un archivo excel.